# Why does the strcat function give me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to concatenate "/bin/" and "touch" so that I will have "/bin/touch".

In my program, I have

```
        char* filePath = malloc((strlen("/bin/") + strlen(rv[0]))* sizeof(char));
        filePath = strcat("/bin/",rv[0])
```

First of all, rv[0] contains a string, "touch". I allocate 10 bytes in memory by using malloc function, and filePath will be the pointer to those 10 bytes of memory. Because, the total length of the string concatenated ("/bin/touch") will be 10.

The program executes normally until the second line which gives me a segmentation fault. Did I make any mistake on the strcat function?

Comment: You're *appending* to a string literal. `strcat` does not work like that. You'd *strcpy* to `filePath` and then *strcat*

Comment: Also you're not allocating space for the null terminator (+ 1), and `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: When copying strings, `strcat()` copies the input string up to and including the zero terminator.   Your `malloc()` size does not allow for the presence of that zero terminator, so is one character shorter than needed.   `strcat()` therefore writes past the allocated end of `filePath` - which gives undefined behaviour.  A call of `strcat()` should not even compile when given two string literals.   If it is, then either your code is forcing it in some way you haven't shown, or your compiler/library is flawed.   I'll bet on the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) for how to use `strcat`:

```
char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src );
```

> Appends a copy of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `src` to the end of the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `dest`.

The first parameter must thus be a pointer to a memory location large enough to hold the bytes of both the C string already there and the C string pointed to by `src`.

You call `strcat("/bin/",rv[0])` and thus try to write into memory where the string literal "/bin/" is stored .. which is normally in readonly memory, thus You get a segmentation fault.

You need to copy `"/bin/"` first into the allocated memory pointed to by `filePath` and then append `rv[0]` there.